# Authenticate username and password in my own login form in django

Tags: django, authentication

i have a class 'user' in my models.py...user has several attributes like userid,username,password,etc. this is a part of my login page login.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
<div>
                    <label><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" required="">                  
                </div>

                <div class="password">
                    <label id="labelp"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Enter password" id="password">
                </div>

                <div class="submitb">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In">

                </div>
</div>
```

i want to retrieve this username and password from here and want to authenticate it against the values i have in my user table(username and password) and then login the user. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the login view provided by Django (`django.contrib.auth.views.login`). You can connect your template to the login view in `urls.py` with the following entry:

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': '/login.html'}),
```

Comment: then would it be able to authenticate with the 'user' table that i have created?

Comment: @Shefali No, this would use the default django `User` model. Why have you created your own user table? I would highly suggest extending the existing model rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. Especially for user authentication, there is a lot of built in security in the existing codebase.

Comment: what i have is a part of a bigger thing...so i have to keep this 'user' table...thanks anyway.

Comment: @Shefali Then what you should do is remove the username and password field from your user model, and instead link your user model to the existing user model with a one-to-one relationship. See the `Extending User Model Using a One-To-One Link` of [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

Comment: i'll give you  a picture what i'm trying to do...i have 2 kinds of users...teachers and students..and i have 2 tables for their details...and i have made a login page for each one of them...so i won't be able to login them separately if i do what you're saying.

Comment: Generally, two types of users would be handled by using [Groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#Creating_users_and_groups)

Comment: @Shefali You could still log them in separately, with two separate login pages - one for members of the `Teachers` group and one for members of the `Students` group

Answer (score 0):

You can login using your form, remember add the {% crsf_token %} in the form and name in your inputs.

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

That is the view, so you get the fields and then use the function authenticate to get the user, and if user and password are correct login; if not return a invalid login error. You can see more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Comment: How are you returning an invalid login error message?

Comment: @AlxVallejo is the same template but with a different context where shows an error

Comment: @AlxVallejo for example: `return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': True})`